# Solving vector equation with multiple unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Given two unknown finite M-dimensional vectors $\mathbf{v},\mathbf{u}\in\mathbb{C}^M$, two finite N-dimensional known vectors $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{C}^N$ and a known matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{M\times N}$, is there an analytic solution for the equation:

$$\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{a}^H+\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{b}^H\in\mathbb{C}^{M\times N}$$
Assume that $N \geqslant 2$ and there are at least $2M$ independent equations.

Comment: Not in general; take for A the identity and for a and b two standard unit vectors, $N=M>2$

Comment: Your comment does not make sense, or I missed something. taking standard unit vectors for a and b gives 0=1 at least once. Maybe my question is not clear, but the meaning is that the equation has a solution. Just asking if there is an expression for an analytic solution or one has to use numerical methods.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood then, I thought your question was if there always is a solution for given $A,a,b$